# Why is the 'in' operator throwing an error with a string literal instead of logging false?

Tags: javascript, string

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) the `in` operator returns `true` if the property exists and accordingly the first example logs true. But when using a string literal, **why is it throwing an error instead of logging false?**

```js
let let1 = new String('test');
console.log(let1.length);
console.log('length' in let1)
```

```js
var let1 = 'test';
console.log(let1.length);
console.log('length' in let1);
```

Comment: I'd assume the temporary wrapper object created for the string is not enumerable ..?

Comment: @Teemu No. There is no temporary wrapper object created at all

Comment: @Bergi Well, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In a sense it is a matter of timing. String literals do not have any properties. The reason that you can call methods and lookup properties on primitive strings is because JavaScript automatically wraps the string primitive in a `String` object when a method call or property lookup is attempted. JavaScript does not interpret the `in` operator as a method call or property lookup so it does not wrap the primitive in an object and you get an error (because a string primitive is not an object).

See [Distinction between string primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects)

Also, the [same docs referenced in your question](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in#Description) specifically note that using `in` on a string primitive will throw an error.

> You must specify an object on the right side of the `in` operator. For
>   example, you can specify a string created with the `String` constructor,
>   but you cannot specify a string literal.

Comment: This is the shortest and most concise correct answer shown.

Comment: Nice. I think I know a lot about JS after working with it for a few years now but I'm still finding out interesting quirks like this.

Answer (score 10):

It **throws** an error because [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) is an operator for objects:

> prop in **object**

but when you declare a string as ``` `` ``` ([` string(template) literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)) or `"" ''` ([",' string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)) you don't create an object.

Check

`typeof new String("x")` ("object")

and

`` typeof `x` `` ("string").

Those are two different things in JavaScript.

Comment: actually my expectation was it will log `false` instead of throwing error.Actually I was doing `if(!(prop in someObj))`

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript operator  [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) only applicable to an `Object`s instances.

When you using constructor `new String('abc')` this will causing creating of  a `String` object instance.

In other side, when you using only string literals or call function `String('abc')` without `new` it creates an string primitive. (like `Number` and `Boolen`)

Some behaviour of primitives and objects is differrent, look at this simple example's output:

```js
console.log(typeof (new String('ddd'))) // "object"
console.log(typeof ('ddd')) // "string"
console.log(eval('1 + 2')) // 3
console.log(eval(new String('1 + 2'))) // {"0":"1","1":" ","2":"+","3":" ","4":"2"}
```

In code where you use methods on string primitives javascript engine automatically wraps primitives with corresponding objects to perform methods call.

But `in` it is not an method call, its language operator an in this case wrapping is not applied.

PS: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3):

`typeof('test') == string` (string literal)

`typof(new String('test')) == object` (string object)

you can't use in with a string literal.

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.

Answer (score 2):

> The in operator can only be used to check if a property is in an
>   object. You can't search in strings, or in numbers, or other primitive
>   types.

The first example works and prints 'true' because `length` is a property of a string object.

The second example doesn't work and gives you an error because you are trying to look for a property `length` in something (a string) that is not an object.

Comment: Right. But `let1` is a string, not an object in the second example.

Comment: The second example wouldn't work because `let1` is not an object.

Comment: Just run the second snippet, the first console.log shows `4`.

Comment: @Teemu, the second console log statement (rightly) throws an error in the second example.

Comment: Yes, but you're saying retrieving the length woud throw the error. On the very first line it logs `4`, the length of `let1`. Take a look at [benvc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55523148/1169519) on this post.

Comment: I believe the question is why the `in` operator throws an error in the second example. The first console log statement is extraneous.

Comment: @VHS, I think the question is actually more like, "*Given that I can access the `length` property of `let1`*, why does the `in` operator throw an error?" Your answer addresses the second part, but ignores the incorrect assumption that `let1` *has* a `length` property when actually it does not.